# Azure vnet peering: property "remoteAddressSpace" unclear

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

When you create a peering between two vnets, you can specify a property called "remoteAddressSpace" in bicep or arm, but not via the portal.
This property holds an array of network prefixes.
I assume these prefixes to be address spaces of the remote vnet and that by specifying one in your peering limits the peer to exactly this address space and that VMs located in other address spaces of the same vnet cannot be reached via this peer.
Is this correct?
I wasn't able to find anything regarding this in the documentation.
br volker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"remoteAddressSpace" property specifies the address range of the peered Vnet when the Peering was created. Or in other words, the address range that is being learnt (in sync) from the peered VNet currently.

While, "remoteVirtualNetworkAddressSpace" specifies the actual address range available on the peered VNet.
The above properties have significance only when the address range of the peered VNet is modified. Refer : [How to re-size Azure virtual networks that are peered](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-resize-azure-virtual-networks-that-are-peered-now-in-preview/)

- I created a Vnet with 10.10.0.0/16 range and peered it to another
  Vnet.
- Then I added 10.11.0.0/16 to this Vnet's address range
- Notice the peeringSyncLevel property
- [image]
- [image]

**P.S:** We cannot modify this property to limit access to a certain subnet of the peered Vnet.